# How can i remove multiple lines from a file based on a pattern that spans multiple lines?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a text formatted like the following:

```
2020-05-02
apple
string
string
string
string
string
2020-05-03
pear
string
string
string
string
string
2020-05-03
apple
string
string
string
string
string
```

Each group has `7` lines = Date, Fruit and then 5 strings.

I would like to delete groups of `7` lines from the file by supplying just the date and the fruit.

So if choose `'2020-05-03'` and `'pear'`

this would remove:

```
2020-05-03
pear
string
string
string
string
string
```

from the file, resulting in this:

```
2020-05-02
apple
string
string
string
string
string
2020-05-03
apple
string
string
string
string
string
```

The file contains thousands of lines, I need a command, probably using sed or awk to:

1. Search for date `2020-05-03`
2. Check if string after date is `pear`
3. delete both lines and following `5` lines

I know i can delete with sed like `sed s'/string//g'`, however i am not sure if i can delete multiple lines.

Note: 
Date followed by fruit is never repeated twice
so

```
2020-05-02
pear
```

would only occur once in the file

How can i acheive this?

Comment: Sounds like `2020-05-03\npear\n(?:.*\n){5}`

Comment: thanks @MonkeyZeus i fixed it

Comment: sed s'/2020-05-03\npear\n(?:.*\n){5}//' doesn't seem to work, but doesn't throw an error

Comment: I'm not a sed expert but maybe it doesn't support non-capturing groups so try `2020-05-03\npear\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n`

Comment: I think the issue is the \n , it does not match, eg: sed s'/2020-05-03\npear//' does not remove the first 2 lines

Comment: Maybe your file is `\r\n` so replace all `\n` from my previous example with `[\r\n]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk,` you may do this:

```
awk -v dt='2020-05-03' -v ft='pear' '$1==dt{p=NR} p && NR==p+1{del=($1==ft)}
del && NR<=p+6{next} 1' file
```

```
2020-05-02
apple
string
string
string
string
string
2020-05-03
apple
string
string
string
string
string
```

**Explanation:**

- `-v dt='2020-05-03' -v ft='pear'`: Supply 2 values to awk from command line
- `$1==dt{p=NR}`: If we find a line with matching date then store line no in variable `p`
- `p && NR==p+1{del=($1==ft)}`: If `p>0` and we are at next line then set a flag `del` to `1` if we have matching fruit name otherwise set that flag to `0`.
- `del && NR<=p+6{next}`: If flag `del` is set then skip next 6 lines
- `1`: Default action to print line

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/2020-05-03/{:a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/7;Ta;/^[^\n]*\npear/d}' file
```

If a line contains `2020-05-03` gather up in total 7 lines and if the 2nd of these lines contains `pear` delete them.